# What does "make up" mean here?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In *Mortal Kombat* (2021), Raiden blocks Shang Tsung with his powers:

> Raiden: You think these tricks will protect you forever? Only a matter
> of time.
>
> Kano: This totally **make up** my superpowers. Think I get it now. It's
> kind of like a box of chocolates. You never know what you're gonna
> get.

What does "make up" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the relevant scene (circa 50:38 in the runtime), and it sounds to me like that line has been misquoted in both the subtitles and the [online transcript](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/mortal-kombat-2021-film-transcript/). Both of those have it as...

> KANO: This totally make up my superpowers.

... which is grammatically incorrect, and makes no sense even in informal spoken English. Whereas, when I listen to the actual dialogue carefully, what I hear is...

> KANO: Uh... just circling back on those superpowers.

... which  does make sense. Because in this context, Kano had just seen several characters, such as Sub-Zero, Liu Kang, and Raiden demonstrate their mystical powers, so he wanted to circle back to the earlier conversation he was having with Liu (while they were walking through the desert) about Liu's fire powers, and the powers he (Kano) might get at some point.